# Why are my embedded style rules working on Github and Dreamweaver but not my school's server?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, winscp

My assignment was to make a website using Dreamweaver with three pages: leftnav.html, rightnav.html, and colorchange.html.  The base is leftnav with a left orientated navigation bar, rightnav is the same except the nav is on the right, and colorchange is the same except that the header and footer image is different.

I styled each page with a .css stylesheet and embedded styles.  All of those style rules were applied across the board to each .html and are functioning well when I open them on Dreamweaver CC or github.  However, my embedded styles are not working when I upload them to my university's server using WinSCP.  I've used WinSCP for the duration of this class and haven't had any issues before.

All the files are up to date and are equivalent to the files in Dreamweaver and on Github, so the code itself shouldn't be a problem.  Just in case, here are the embedded style rules from changecolor.html:

```
<head>
...
...
<link href="project7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#banner, #footer {
    background-image: url(beigebg.jpg);
}
#content {
    border-left: 250px solid #F0E1BA;
}
</style>
</head>
```

If anyone could give me something to try, or if you need more info to get an idea of what's going on, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: have you tried CMD+Option+J to check for console errors and look at the DOM to verify <style> is in the HTML? you can also click on elements in that DOM "Elements" hierarchy panel to see associated styles, or use CMD+Option+C then click an element in your actual browser

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: another possibility is `href="./project7.css"` or just `/project7.css` but probably not

Comment: @CarolMcKay [this](http://csit.parkland.edu/~kprochilo1/kp152/leftnav.html) is the link to my school's server that isn't working properly, and [this](https://kprochi2.github.io/colorchange.html) is through my github repo that is up and running

Comment: @neaumusic I validated using W3C and the elements are stacked correctly.  They're in <head> which is within <html>, and if they weren't, I'm pretty sure the style rules would appear as simple text above the page which isn't happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The beige is actually coming from "colorchange.html" as seen in the style sidebar

If you want the green color, you can either increase [specificity](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjh6dmtoffNAhVJKGMKHeZWBCMQFggtMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcss-tricks.com%2Fspecifics-on-css-specificity%2F&usg=AFQjCNGn8ijfiVedyiv-lE1BZeoeIcNgEQ&sig2=8xfCvJCHNCVnWclPDdIa3w&bvm=bv.127178174,d.cGc), use `background-image: url(...) !important` or figure out how that additional `colorchange.html` is being included

If you want the beige color, you can add the style to `project7.css` or figure out how to include `colorchange.html`

[image: one]
[image: two]

Comment: That article was super helpful and !important seems to have done the trick for today, so thank you.

This seems a bit of the easy way out to simply add !important on when I need it.  I was under the impression that an embedded style rule would have outweighed project7.css.  Why is this not the case in this instance when it's worked before?

Also, why is it an issue that the beige is coming from colorchange.html?

Comment: Yea they call it a hack when it's improper, but it does work. I think that inline style ultimately win out, eg `<div id="banner" style="background:url(...)></div>"` though you shouldn't really touch HTML frequently, and I don't really know what's going on with the files.. anyways glad to help though